# Where to create the desktop configuration file of an app so that it can be locked to launcher?

Tags: gnome, launcher

On GNOME desktop environment, I have added an app to favorites and I can launch the app from that list clicking on the icon of the favorites list.

But when I launch, a similar icon of the app appears side by side. I mean, two icons of the app are showing instead of one. Where should I create a `.desktop` file so that when I click on the app icon, it launches with no redundant icon?

Comment: `.local/share/applications` .(pretty sure this will be closed as a duplicate)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yep, thanks for the correction. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this application is for just one user that you are using you should create the `.desktop` in the `.local/share/applications`

But if you need to make the application global so that all other users in your system can use it so you should create it in the `/usr/share/applications`

Comment: How is the icon to be decided?